# Android Auth0 Lock Clear Cache

Tags: android, google-signin, auth0

I'm integrating Auth0's Lock as part of the login process of my app, as to adhere with the web implementation of Auth0's login.

I followed the directions in the `README.md` of the [Lock (Android)](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.Android) repository and I'm able to login with Google without issues.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to indicate to Auth0 or the Lock that I have logged my user out, so I'm never again prompted to choose which account I want to login as when I re-login.  I currently store my session info in `SharedPreferences` and my current logout procedure is to clear that data.  I am able to navigate back to the UI of the login screen, but as soon as I touch on the Google icon to login via Google, Auth0 authenticates against my previously logged in user without prompting me to enter my credentials.

Is there an official way to clear the cache with Auth0's Lock?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to follow the [Android Quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android) guide, more specifically, the part about [session handling](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/android/03-session-handling) where it describes one possible way of maintaining a user session after login.

The last section of the session handling part is about how to achieve log out. The provided sample code is the following:

```
private void logout() {
  // Clear credentials (depends on how you store them in the first place)
  setUserCredentials(null);

  // Navigate to Lock login screen
  startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Have in mind that the `setUserCredentials` is specific to that particular sample, the general idea would be that you store the received tokens somewhere and then provide the user the option to log out, which triggers the cleanup of the tokens and the redirection to the login screen.

Comment: I was following the Quickstart guide and did download the sample which you describe.  The issue I found was that the `setUserCredentials(null);` method call to the `CredentialsManager` class only clears out the credentials from the `SharedPreferences` of the app.  It didn't appear that either the Auth0 or Lock libraries referenced those shared preferences.  Even ever I cleared the credentials in the manner which you suggested, I was still not able to choose which Google I account I wanted to login as the next time I tried to login.

Comment: I don't have sufficient knowledge on the Android SDK to provide anything other than guesses, but in your update you mentioned that you are able to get to the login screen, but after choosing Google you get automatically logged in. Is there a chance that this might be Google specific, because when you select Google social login Lock will just delegate the authentication to Google. Try to use other type of authentication (username/password) just for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: João Angelo, we don't have username/password authentication setup with out account, we only use social logins.  With that said, I tried logging in with a FB account instead of a Google account and saw the same issue.  I was able to clear the webview cache which cleared the cookies for webviews within the app, and that helped it on Lollipop+ devices, but I have a device running KitKat which, once logged in, never gives the option to log in with a different account, or validate the credentials for that account.  When logging in it just automatically logs them in.

Comment: I feel your pain, running into this myself on iOS.  Clearing the cache of the webviews was the answer in the past.  Now it's not an option, so there has to be some kind of switch you can flip.